# Vagrant port forwarding for Mysql

Tags: mysql, vagrant, portforwarding, vagrantfile

I am trying to setup port forwarding in Vagrantfile to connect to guest mysqld from host system, but get `reading initial communication packet` error.
Host: Yosemite, Guest: Trusty, vagrant 1.7.4

Vagrantfile(host):

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3309
```

my.ini(guest):

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

8080 forwarding works like a charm.

`mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -p` from guest also works.

`mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P 3309 -uroot -p` from host results with `reading initial communication packet` error.

When I telnet from host, the connection instantly closes:

```
$ telnet localhost 3309
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Port forwarding works when I ssh to vagrant box from host:

```
$ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 -L3308:localhost:3306
```

Then I can connect from host `mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P3308 -uroot -p` without problems, which I use as a temporary workaround.

Comment: do you have firewall rules that would block traffic on those ports ?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri no, it was my first suspect. There is no single iptable rule. Anyway, I tried to tunnel with ssh, and it works without problems.

Comment: right but with the tunneling you still use the ssh port.

Comment: well, even with ssh tunnel over 2222, it should use 3306 on guest system to connect to mysqld, and 3309 on host for client. Anyway, I confirm there is no iptable rules on guest, and firewall is turned off on host.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

was finally able to make it work -

edit the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file and make sure, either

- you have `bind-address           = 0.0.0.0`
- or you comment the line `#bind-address ...`

You may need to add it to the mysqld section of the my.cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

make sure to restart your mysql server after the change

```
$ sudo service mysql restart
```

Then you can connect from your host - so I first had an error like

```
$ mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P 3309 -uroot -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '172.16.42.2' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

so I came back to the guest and did

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -p
...
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'172.16.42.2' WITH GRANT OPTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Then I had no issue to connect from the host machine

```
$ mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P 3309 -uroot -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 36
Server version: 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: Thanks Frederic. It also works with `bind-address = 10.0.2.15` in my.cnf.

Comment: Apparently, virtualbox uses this interface for port forwarding. I couldn't find a way to forward ports to lo interface other than ssh to the box, which is not very convenient, yet kinda make sense.

Comment: right with VirtualBox, Vagrant requires the first network device attached to the virtual machine to be a NAT device. The NAT device is used for port forwarding, which is how Vagrant gets SSH access to the virtual machine.

Comment: I want to add that it kind of took me some time for it to work (this answer is good). (at first I would get "ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 2" even when I've got all the configuration settings "properly", I gave up so I decided to use the ssh forward tunnel workaround, which I could finally made it work, but by then, I tried again directly mysql to teh port, without tunnel, and it worked... So others, maybe just be patient, reload vagrant and mysql several times before giving up.

Answer (score 2):

The first answer is right but not enough.when I connect MySQL, I get a error:

> Host '10.0.2.2' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Solution:

> create user 'root'@'10.0.2.2' identified by 'password';
>
> grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'10.0.2.2' with grant option;
>
> flush privileges;

aha, all problems are solved,

Answer (score 2):

Personally I don't bother with modifying MySQL for development Vagrant boxes - it's time consuming and difficult to script in a provisioner meaning you have to do it by hand every time you `vagrany destroy` or a new developer starts contributing. Instead, I connect via SSH Tunnel which is made super easy using Vagrant's generated `private_key` file. No additional post-install tweaking necessary.

Follow these steps to SSH Tunnel with SequelPro, MySql Workbench, or any other client that supports SSH connectivity:

- Choose SSH connection option
- The "Host" in SSH mode becomes localhost or specifically `127.0.0.1` (more predictable cross-os)
- The username/password is the database username/password. For development you can just use `root` and the password is defined/created in the provisioner (see snippet below)
- The SSH username is `Vagrant`
- No SSH password - just use the `private_key` for the Vagrant machine instead, located in `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox` in the root of your VM project; note that on most OS's **this directory, and all starting with a `.` are hidden**

To automate installation and root password creation, add this to your Vagrant provisioner script file (`config.vm.provision` in Vagrantfile), commonly named `provisioner.sh`:

```
debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password SuperSecretPasswordHere'
debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password SuperSecretPasswordHere'

apt-get install -y mysql-server
```

Hope this helps save someone else some time!