# Connect to MySQL from outside vagrant

Tags: mysql, vagrant

I would like to connect with mycli to the MySQL server running inside a vagrant instance.

My basic Vagrantfile looks like the following code snippet:

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.ssh.shell = "bash -c 'BASH_ENV=/etc/profile exec bash'"

  config.vm.box = "debian/wheezy64"

  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "misc/bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8082

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/",
    owner: "vagrant",
    group: "www-data",
    mount_options: ["dmode=775,fmode=664"],
    create: true

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.memory = 1536
      vb.cpus = 1
  end
end
```

To install the neccessary software I am using the following code snippet:

```
echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password $DBPASSWD" | debconf-set-selections
echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password $DBPASSWD" | debconf-set-selections

echo "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/dbconfig-install boolean true" | debconf-set-selections
echo "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/app-password-confirm password $DBPASSWD" | debconf-set-selections
echo "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/mysql/admin-pass password $DBPASSWD" | debconf-set-selections
echo "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/mysql/app-pass password $DBPASSWD" | debconf-set-selections
echo "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/reconfigure-webserver multiselect none" | debconf-set-selections

sudo apt-get install -y apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server php5-mysql php5 phpmyadmin php5-cli php5-curl vim
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/phpmyadmin.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf

sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo a2enmod php5
sudo cp /var/www/misc/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

sudo service apache2 restart

mysql -uroot -p$DBPASSWD -e "CREATE USER '$DBUSER'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$DBPASSWD';GRANT ALL ON *.* TO '$DBUSER'@'localhost';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;CREATE DATABASE $DBNAME;"
mysql -u$DBUSER -p$DBPASSWD $DBNAME < /var/www/db.sql
```

I think my problem is the user credentials which I am storing into the database. But I couln't figure out answer.

Comment: What are you expecting? Are any errors thrown?

Comment: you can review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146223/vagrant-port-forwarding-for-mysql/33172400#33172400

Comment: $DBUSER and $DBPASSWD are not shown, but probably if they are root and empty, it'll probably work, right?

Comment: yeah working like charm inside vagrant.

Answer (score 2):

If you are connecting from outside of the vm, you'll need to add a port mapping that listens on the host and forwards requests to the guest. Similar to the one defined for http here:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8082
```

For mysql (assuming your mysql listens on the default port):

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 33060
```

After, modifying the Vagrant file, `vagrant reload`.

Then when connecting, specify the port

```
mysql -P 33060 -u user -p database
```

Comment: I had added the port mapping for mysql and tried to connect with your command `mysql -P 33600 -umyuser -pmypw mydb` and get the following error: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Comment: You may need to restart the vm, not just provision. Did you try `vagrant reload`?

Comment: yeah I did `destroy` and `up` but still same error :/

Comment: Try with `mysql --protocol=TCP ...`

Comment: Then I get the error `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0`

Comment: Check if you have firewall rules enabled for the host or guest that would prevent the connection.

Comment: Default MySQL port is 3606, not 3660

Answer (score 1):

on top of what JRD said on the port forwarding, you need to make sure mysql listens on all port and not just locally

edit the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file and make sure, either

- you have `bind-address           = 0.0.0.0`
- or you comment the line `#bind-address ...`

make sure to restart your mysql server after the change

```
$ sudo service mysql restart
```

Then you can connect from your host - In case you get the following error

```
$ mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P 33600 -uroot -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '172.16.42.2' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

Then came back to the guest and do

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -p
...
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'172.16.42.2' WITH GRANT OPTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Then you should have no issue to connect from the host machine

```
$ mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P 33600 -uroot -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 36
Server version: 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: still getting the error `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0` and entry in hosts.deny and I did `ALL:ALL` in hosts.allow

Comment: rather than `ALL:ALL` put `mysqld: ALL` in hosts.allow file