# Connect to Vagrant MySQL server from host throws error 2013

Tags: mysql, vagrant

I struggle connecting from host machine to a MySQL server running inside a Vagrant instance. My small Vagrantfile is:

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.ssh.shell = "bash -c 'BASH_ENV=/etc/profile exec bash'"
  config.vm.box = "debian/wheezy64"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "misc/bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8082
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3360, host: 33600
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.22"

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/",
    owner: "vagrant",
    group: "www-data",
    mount_options: ["dmode=775,fmode=664"],
    create: true

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.memory = 1536
      vb.cpus = 1
  end
end
```

So then I tried to connect from host to MySQL like this:

```
mysql -h 192.168.33.22 -P 33600 -uroot -proot
```

And get the following error:

> ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

**Things I tried to solve the problem:**

- Add `mysqld: ALL` to hosts.allow
- Checked hosts.deny for any entry (is completely empty)
- comment the line `bind-address` in /etc/mysql/my.conf
- did `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;` and restarted mysql service

**some more information:**

- never played around with iptables nor blocked any port
- connecting from inside vagrant works like charm
- just this vagrant instance is running
- running Debian 8

Comment: 33.33.33.10? Using a US military IP? That'll end well...

Comment: so changing it to `192.168.33.22` doesn't work either

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to MySQL from outside vagrant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34008226/connect-to-mysql-from-outside-vagrant)