# Vagrant - Symfony MySQL Connection denied

Tags: mysql, symfony, vagrant

I set up my Vagrant Box and run it.
Everything is fine, i can access via SSH and from ssh to my MySQL DB with User: admin Passwort: 123

Now i want to set up my dbal connection in symfony with same parameters.
But when i try to generate entity with the console - i get an access denied error.

here are the configs

**vagrant config.yaml**

```
mysql:
install: '1'
settings:
    version: '5.6'
    root_password: '123'
    override_options: {  }
adminer: 0
users:
    mysqlnu_frgjl84yupmt:
        name: admin
        password: '123'
databases:
    mysqlnd_u4je0vjf3q4p:
        name: symfony
        sql: ''
grants:
    mysqlng_vbmahcu6w4us:
        user: admin
        table: '*.*'
        privileges:
            - ALL
```

**symfony parameters.yml**

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: ~
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: admin
    database_password: 123
```

I also tried

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: ~
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: admin
    database_password: '123'

parameters:
    database_host: localhost
    database_port: ~
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: admin
    database_password: 123

parameters:
    database_host: localhost
    database_port: ~
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: admin
    database_password: '123'
```

I hope you can help me fix this problem :(

Thanks a lot

Comment: I found out, that i can use symfony cli when i'm on vagrant ssh.
But not from my local system outside vagrant

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/33172400/4296747 to access mysql from your host machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have user `admin@127.0.0.1` which means something like:

*a user with login `admin` that may login from host `127.0.0.1`*

To log into MySQL form outside (from another host actually, because `127.0.0.1` is localhost) you need to create user that will allow you to do that.

Comment: Thanks - i got the problem with the CLI. 
When i use ssh on Vagrant then i can use SF Cli.