# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, vagrant, virtualbox

I am using vagrant command line tool.After i used vagrant up command,i am getting the below error in my browser while running.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL
>   server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in
>   Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService()
>   (line 79 of
>   /drupal/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php).

Comment: Is MySQL running and if so, is that the correct location for the socket file?

Comment: Are you conbevting to a mysql instance running on the box, or elsewhere?

Comment: I am getting this error while running this command: mysql -uroot -p pswd   ERROR:Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2).

Comment: you run the command from inside the VM or from your host ? are you sure that mysql is running ?

Comment: check this one then http://stackoverflow.com/a/33172400/4296747

Answer (score 0):

Please check the mysql service is running inside the VM.

service mysqld status